# Java Serialization API that handles cyclic dependencies and polymorphism

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

is there a serialization API/Framework for Java that can handle (1) Polymorphism and (2) Cyclic Dependencies. Also, it should be possible to (3) serialize existing classes without changing them.

I have tried out Gson and Jackson. Gson provides (1) and (3) quite well, but seems to lack providing cyclic dependencies. Jackson provides (1) and (2) but uses annotations, so that the classes need to be changed (However, this can be handled using Mixed-in). However, to handle polymorphism the super class must be annotated with its sub-classes. That is a big problem, because I am developing some kind of framework, where the user can add his own sub-classes. So, I don’t have a full list of the sub-classes.

One problem with Json-based frameworks is, of course, that Json has a tree structure whereas I need to serialize any kind of Graph. Does anyone know a good framework for that?

Comment: JSON construction is not serialization.

Comment: That wasn't what I wanted to say. GSON, for example, can be used to serialize Java objects using the JSON format.